# How is the liquid refrigerant distributed throughout the system before start

Tags: ac

When an air conditioning system is at rest (eg before starting) how is the liquid refrigerant distributed throughout the system? I would think that the expansion valve would remain slightly open, allowing the liquid part of the refrigerant to flow at the bottom of the system and the vapor at the top. If this is true, how liquid refrigerant is prevented to flow into the compressor?

Ref pic below:
Do we all agree that the gauges on the manifold set are indicating a relationship between gas T and P and that this relationship would only be true if vapor pressure exists (liquid phase in the system)? The gas pressure in the system (no liquid phase) will not provide a correct T for the P indicated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The refrigerant should equalize through the system and reach ambient temps. I'm not sure if at that point whether any is left in a liquid form or not, but would assume it wouldn't be. Leaving this as a comment, because I really don't know for sure.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: There's definitely some liquid left. Think about: If it were all gas, pressure depends on temperature and amount of gas left. If there's liquid, pressure depends on temperature only. (Compare nitrogen and liquid gas bottle)

Comment: The only way to prevent liquid from flowing into the compressor with system turned off is fitting a liquid line solenoid valve (LLSV) right after the condenser. This is done with bus HVAC systems, since, apparently, liquid refrigerant inside the sump of a transit compressor (google for Carrier 05G if you want an example) at startup is a very bad thing (the refrigerant displaces the compressor's oil). The TXV can definitely open up with an inactive system, since the suction line is warm when no refrigerant is flowing through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, yes, there is always liquid refrigerant in the system at idle.
Looking through tables, the minimum amount of R134a in car ACs is about 500g, some cars have twice or more.
[chemistry] 500g R134a is about 5mol, which has a volume of 115l (30gallons) at 25°C (77F).[/chemistry]
Now, we know that at that temperature, the AC system has a pressure of about 5Bar (72psi), which by the way is the pressure shown on the gauges on the picture.
Applying the ideal gas equation V<sub>1</sub>/V<sub>2</sub>=p<sub>2</sub>/p<sub>1</sub> and the given amount, at that pressure, **the gas (and so the AC system) should have a volume of 115l/5=23l (6gallons)**.
Since a cars AC system for sure does not have this volume (may be larger cars, but they also have more refrigerant), there must be liquid R134 in the system!
(Keep in mind, the ideal gas equations are only valid for ideal gases. Many gases can be treated ideal, but only when far away from their boiling point)

When sitting idle, it is very likely that there will be liquid refrigerant around the compressor, since it often is the lowest mounted part of the system.

I can't back it up, but I *think* liquid refrigerant in the compressor is not as bad as water is for a combustion motor. In a combustion motor, cylinder valves are opened into the inside, and higher pressure inside closes the valves even harder. But in a compressor, the outlet valve opens outwards when the pressure is high enough. So, liquid in the cylinder (or what ever it is) can escape and does not cause hydrolock. This *does* put stress on the compressor, but as long as this only happens when switching on the AC, and not always, the compressor can take it.

Comment: A/C compressors are **not** designed to pump liquids...

Comment: Thanks Sweber for your explanation, what you are saying makes perfectly sense and unswer thoroughly my question.

Comment: @SolarMike: I'd say it's not good for them. But It doesn't destroy them immediately.

Comment: That said, liquid refrigerant harms reed valves. That's a matter of fact. But the real harm comes from a continuous liquid slugging condition, caused, for example, by a TXV whose bulb lost physical contact with the suction line. Not the 1-2 secs maximum of getting rid of the minimal liquid refrigerant slug that made its way inside the compressor (the coldest part in the system when the liquid prefers migrating to it) overnight.

Comment: A variable displacement compressor usually starts pumping in the minimum displacement swashplate angle so it's the kind of compressor which gets harmed less. And automotive compressors usually don't come with an oil sump, so, anyway, there's not so much oil that can be displaced by the liquid refrigerant like with a, automotively speaking, Harrison A6 compressor. Placing the compressor high in the system (i.e. on top of the engine) can prevent liquid slugging but, at the same time, makes the compressor more vulnerable to the reduced lubricant return rate caused by a low refrigerant charge.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any liquid in the "intake" side of the system.  This is largely prevented by the Thermal Expansion Valve (TXP), or on older vehicles, an orifice tube.  These parts reside in, or just before, the evaporator - the heat exchanger internal to the vehicle in the HVAC housing under the dashboard.

At normal "at rest" temperatures and pressure, all the refrigerant will be in a gas phase.  Exacly like Paulster opined.

Provided the system is not overfilled, the refrigerant will remain a dense gas until compressed and the temperature lowered - this pressure comes from the compressor, and the gas-to-liquid phase change will occur in the condenser (another heat exchanger, usually in front of the radiator).

If liquid were allowed to reach the intake side of the compressor, the unit would "hydrolock" and likely destroy the compressor if you weren't lucky enough to burn or break the belt first.

### Answer to comment:

@Simone  I'm not sure exactly what you are saying, but most gases have a fairly high boiling point compared to refrigerant.  (R134a is about -15 degrees F).  I'd rather call it "gas pressure" than vapor pressure, but in any case you can put thousands of psi of oxygen, helium, argon, and carbon dioxide in a tank, but none of it will be in liquid phase at normal "human" temperatures.

It all follows the Ideal Gas Law, **PV=nRT**, where pressure * volume is proportional to the moles (amount) * temperature * a constant (measurement units).  The liquid phase (if any) is comparitively un-compressible (which is why it would break the compressor) and would not affect the pressure of a manifold gauge set reading.  The gauges have no clue about temperature, only gas pressure.  (There are fancy manifold sets with thermometers built in, but the gauges are still ignorant of temperature.)  A chart is needed to determine if the observed pressures are appropriate for the specific refrigerant type and operating temperatures.

At rest, since I'm fairly certain all [R134a] refrigerant will be well above -15 degrees F, there should be no liquid anywhere in the system.  As temperature increases, so will gas pressure.  If pressure decreases suddenly, as with a small orifice discharging into the evaporator, a severe pressure drop *must* beget a severe temperature drop, since volume, moles, and the constant are not changing.  Viola!  Enjoy the "air conditioning"...

Comment: Makes sense what you are saying, however the test and charging manifold gauges used for servicing the ac system have a direct correlation between pressure and temperature. This correlation exists for vapor pressure, and vapor pressure exists only if we have a liquid state in the system. Since you said that there is not a liquid state at rest, we will not have a correlation between temperature and pressure while the system is not running. Am I right?

Comment: What @Simone means: liquid R134a exposed to room temperature will for sure start to boil. But if it is enclosed inside a containment like the AC system, it will boil until the gas/vapor reaches a pressure of 5bar, and then stop. I mean, that's exactly how an ac works: by altering the pressure and make the 134a evaporate and condense. Now, assume a very low temperature and lots of liquid 134a in the evaporator in the car. When parking the car in the sun, the evaporator becomes very hot, much hotter than the AC pipe under the hood. The 134a will condense there, right before the compressor.

Comment: @Sweber Nah, not a chance.  There's no impediment to flow between the evaporator and any "AC pipe under the hood".  Unless the interior of the car falls well below -15 degrees F, there won't be any liquid in the evaporator.  The orifice tube/TXV is pretty meaningless in this scenario as well.  At rest, there's no compression, and the system will equalize to one uniform pressure.

Comment: Even if the interior was -20 degrees F, and the engine compartment 200 degrees F, the system will flow in both directions until the gas pressure is equal.  You will never see a major difference on a manifold gauge set with the system at rest for any period of time.  Any theoretical "liquid" in the evaporator would seize the compressor.  It doesn't happen, because it can't.  There's no way to thermally isolate liquid from the gas, as there is no "valve" that sections off one part of the system from the other.  Even a TXV is never fully closed.

Comment: I don't know where "5 bar" came from, but I assure you that even a cool fall day, typical "at rest" system pressure is probably 60-80 psi, or very close to 5 bar.  NONE of that is liquid.  I suppose if the windows were open in Alaska, there might be an issue.  Again, the Ideal Gas Law defines this behavior, and you can't have a pool of -15 degree F liquid next to anything gaseous at a higher temperature.  The system will thermally equalize, ALWAYS, and unless the entire system is kept below the [very high] boiling point, there is no liquid phase that can be sustained.

Comment: Even the output of the compressor is still gaseous, until cooled by the condensor.  The pressure is certainly increased, perhaps as much as 350 psi (call it 25 bar) on R12, in the desert.  But the output pipe is *wicked* hot.  You have to get rid of the "T" in the gas law to get it to condense to liquid.

Comment: This only happens with the system running, and enough cooling airflow across the condenser heat exchanger to lower the "T" in the gas law.

Comment: @SteveRacer: I think you have a big misunderstanding on what boiling point is. That -15F / -28°C ist only true at ambient pressure. Increase pressure, and it boils at higher temperature. At 5Bar, it boils at 70F/20°C. At 175F/80°C, it would boil at 25Bar.  And didn't say you have -15F liquid next to warmer gas. Finally, you are arguing with ideal gas laws. But they assume gases which never condensate - and aren't valid for a gas which is near to boiling point.

Comment: I agree with Sweber.
It does not make any sense to me that an AC system at rest would contain only refrigerant gas. If this would be true, by measuring refrigerant temperature and pressure we would easily calculate the amount of refrigerant contained in the system.

Comment: Everybody who serviced an AC system knows that the only way to know the amount of gas contained in the system is through a refrigerant recovery procedure and not by using a pressure gauge. So, to me, an AC system at rest contain liquid refrigerant and vapor. How liquid is prevented to enter the compressor remain a mystery. Perhaps the suction created in the low side is vaporizing any liquid during start?

Comment: As an ASE Advanced Master and a certified MACS refrigerant handler, I have serviced one or two systems.  And I *know* recovery systems use a sensitive scale on the tank, which is tared to zero on initiation.  So this (in combination with a temp sensor) is how a recovery system estimates the weight (moles, "n" from Ideal Gas Law) of refrigerant recovered.  You absolutely *could* determine the amount of refrigerant from a manifold gauge set, if you know then exact moles in the system and the equilibrium temperature of the system (assuming all gas phase; Aye, there's the rub...)

Comment: I totally agree with @sweber about the shift in boiling point v. pressure.  But I think all of us may be missing the "volume" issue.  Certainly, in a standard 30 lb. tank of R134a, you can shake it and feel the liquid phase.  But this is 20-40 *times* the amount in a typical automotive system.  Agreed, the amount (moles) of refrigerant is set to allow easy phase changes from liquid-to-gas in the evaporator, and gas-to-liquid in a well-cooled condensor.  But I suggest that these parameters are not chosen at random.  This is not a 30 lb. tank or a 14 oz. recharge can at high pressure.

Comment: My ultimate assertion is that given a *properly* charged automotive system, at rest for a "long" period of time (input compressor T = output compressor T= evaporator fin T = condenser fin T) in most real world situations there is not enough "n" to have any liquid in the system at reasonable ambient temperatures.

Comment: Again, I'm talking about an open system that has thermally equalized "at rest".  Of course I won't suggest there's no liquid phase after the condenser on a running system.  I simply cannot accept there's liquid phase in a system that is at rest and thermally equalized above the boiling point, given the "n" moles and volume that exists with mobile A/C.  I could be wrong - wouldn't be a virgin - but *show* me how for V volume, n moles, P pressure, and T temperature how you would have liquid condensed anywhere in a thermal equilibrium at rest in normal ambient.

Comment: @SteveRacer: I already DID show it in my answer. If it were all gas, and ideal gas laws would be applicable, a AC system would have a minimum volume of 6 gallons. And... in normal ambient.. what's that? There's always pressure on the AC system.

Comment: Or, let's turn it around: There are thousands of websites stating pressure of resting AC systems, but show me a single one which puts pressure in relation to amount of refrigerant.

Comment: Are you suggesting that adding more refrigerant would not change resting pressure?  Or recovering half the charge amount? (I was going to say dump...) Let's turn it aroundaround.  7 gallons is about the volume of a 30lb R134a tank.  Draw a vacuum and then add 14-20 *ounces* of R134a.  (That roughly approximates a vehicle A/C system.) You really think that tank, at say 70 degrees F, is going to contain part liquid?  What if it was a 70 or 700 gallon tank?  You won't get to the condensation point because there's not enough "n" to drive the P in such a large volume.

Comment: The output of the compressor is high pressure, high temperature gas phase.  NOT liquid.  You only condense to liquid by removing the T, which happens in the aptly-named condenser.  The reason those "internet" charts work (sort-of) is because the system is assumed to be ideally charged, with just the right moles/volume ratio.  Larger capacity; more refrigerant needed.  The resting pressure will certainly depend on the state of charge.  Checking a system at rest with a hi/lo pressure of 15/15 is a sure sign of a leak.  70/70 is probably healthy, but varies (of course) with ambient temperature.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of liquid refrigerant remains nearly the same regardless of if the system is running or not. An A/C system is an oddly shaped container but it is still a container.If you have a 30 pound cylinder with one pound of refrigerant in it you can shake it and feel the liquid. A small amount of refrigerant evaporates and that gas pressurizes the cylinder until the remaining liquid will no longer evaporate. There is no compressor involved. The liquid remains in the cylinder. The same thing happens in the A/C system. As the compressor pressurizes the gas to a liquid an equal amount is evaporating on the suction side. There is always a small amount of refrigerant gas pressurizing the container preventing the evaporation of the remaining liquid. The compressor could only compress the small amount that has evaporated but as it does low pressure evaporates an equal amount. The volume of the liquid refrigerant would only change as much and the same as it does in a dial a charge.